# How do I set the groupHeaderTemplate for Kendo Grid column using data attributes?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to be able to take advantage of data attributes to handle configuring my grid, but can't figure out how to set the `groupHeaderTemplate` for a column.

The documentation suggests I use `data-group-header-template`: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/data-attribute-initialization

```
<table id="grid"
    data-role="grid"
    data-bind="source: dataSource">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th 
        data-field="ID"
        data-group-header-template="t_name">ID</th> <!-- Doesn't work! :( -->
      </tr>
  </head>
</table>

<script>
  kendo.bind($('body'), viewModel);
</script>
```

How do I set the group header template on a column without directly calling the `$.fn.kendoGrid`?

UPDATE:

I checked the source code for Kendo Grid, and it doesn't seem to set all the properties defined on the columns.

For reference, in `Grid._columns`...

```
// using HTML5 data attributes as a configuration option
return {
  field: field,
  type: type,
  sortable: sortable !== "false",
  filterable: filterable !== "false",
  groupable: groupable !== "false",
  menu: menu,
  template: th.attr(kendo.attr("template")),
  width: cols.eq(idx).css("width")
};
```

Later, when writing the group row html in `Grid._groupRowHtml`

```
template = column.groupHeaderTemplate; // Wasn't set in _columns. :(
if (template) {
    text  = typeof template === FUNCTION ? template(data) : kendo.template(template)(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it correctly.  The contents of the attribute should however refer to the id of a script element *containing* your Kendo template.

```
<script id="myscriptname" type="text/x-kendo-template>
    <!--script markup/code here-->
</script>

<table id="grid"
    data-role="grid"
    data-bind="source: dataSource">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th 
        data-field="ID"
            data-group-header-template="myscriptname">ID</th>
      </tr>
  </head>
</table>
```

You also need to have called `kendo.bind`, passing in an element that is above your table in the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: I was referring to the template id, I didn't include it in the example though. It still doesn't work, neither does using string template: http://jsfiddle.net/Ze2bw/3/ . I checked the kendo grid source code, It doesn't seem to map the header or footer templates from any HTML defined columns; it only maps the `template` property.